# How to make responsive html5 video in fancybox and videoJS

Tags: jquery, html, video, responsive-design, fancybox

How can I make a html5 video responsive inside fancybox which is responsive already? This is the code I have so far :

```
<a class="preview" href="#inline123">
    <img class="item" src="/thumbs/thumb.jpg" width="{_file.IMAGE_W}" height="{_file.IMAGE_H}">
</a>

<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="inline123">
        <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vid" style="width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;" controls poster="/thumbs/thumb.jpg" preload="none" id="123">
            <source src="/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="/video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
        <script>
        // <![CDATA[
        $(".preview").fancybox({
            'beforeShow': function(){
                $(window).on({
                    'resize.fancybox' : function(){
                        $.fancybox.update();
                    }
                });
             },
             'afterClose': function(){
                  $(window).off('resize.fancybox');
             },
             width      : '640',
             height     : '360',
             fitToView  : true,
             closeClick : false,
             openEffect : 'none',
             closeEffect: 'none',
             closeBtn   : 'true',
             scrolling  : 'no',
        });
        // ]]>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if `#inline123` has a fixed width, then it isn't responsive, is it?

Comment: Yes I removed that in the meantime and I have edited my code above to reflect where I am at now. I had to get past an 'isotope' jquery plugin problem which I was able to do using info from this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433718/how-to-make-responsive-html5-video-in-fancybox In particular using the beforeShow and afterClose methods. I'm also using videoJS with my videos and that is also causing a problem. With videoJS disabled everything is working correctly. So now to re-enable videoJS and see if I can stop it conflicting with the responsiveness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so it ended up the video tag needed to look like this

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vid" controls poster="/image/poster.jpg" preload="none" id="123" width="auto" height="auto" style="width:100% !important; height:auto !important">
```

**width="auto" height="auto"** is what fixes the videojs problem. I didn't realize that *auto* was a valid value. According to this http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/videodrome/videojs/ it also makes things work in *IE9*

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the place the video inside a div and give the video with `width: 100%` and `height: auto`. Also, set the holding div with the necessary width and height sizes.

Check out my fiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tushar2289/KCqGx/)

Comment: Yes I already have that part working fine, it is videoJS causing the problem. Without videoJS enabled everything works, with it enable I lose responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

This answer never helped me ,after hours of try and luck, I found a good jquery solution , I created a function to handle the with :

```
//computing player size 
function computePlayerSize(){

    var playerParent= $(".video-js").parent();

    var parentWidth = playerParent.width();

    var parentHeight = playerParent.height();

    var aspectRatio = 9/16; // you can change AR to meet your requirement

    var playerHeight = parentWidth*aspectRatio;

    var playerWidth = parentWidth;


    return {"width": playerWidth ,"height" : playerHeight}
}
```

the  tag must be in a wrapper with css :

```
.playerWrapper{
display:inline-block;
padding:0;
}
```

Next lets init videojs

```
//attach the computePlayerSize() to get the first width and height to match the player wrapper
var videoJsParam = $.extend(computePlayerSize(),{
techOrder: ["html5","flash"]
});


//snapShopPlayer
videojs("snapShotVideo",videoJsParam,function(){

snapShotPlayer = this;

window.playerInstance = snapShotPlayer;

//if resized ,then recompute the player size
$(window).on("resize",function(){

//if resized , then lets get the new width and height 
newPlayerSize = computePlayerSize();

window.playerInstance.width(newPlayerSize.width).height(newPlayerSize.height);

});//end if resized


});
```

Not the best , but works like charm